# WINDEV - Default Paper Format for Repport

Tags: windev

In Windev 19, when I create a new repport, I always have "A4" as default paper format, I want Windev to always use Letter 8.5 / 11 format.

Somebody know how to modify this?

I use Windev 19 french version, it's the reason why it A4 as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Unfortunately the french version sets it to A4, no way to change that and it bothered me too.

I started to work with the English version of Windev lately and noticed that it sets "US Letter" by default with this version. If you are like me, you might endup liking it better this way;

With the added bonus of having the WLangage already set in english mode without having to tweak the settings like I used to in the French version; overall the whole thing feels more natural (IF THEN ELSE END SWITCH CASE string int bool etc...) if you have any prior background experiences with other classic languages like me.

Another bonus advantage I see was that the english version always comes out when the french version has been stabilized enough :)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can change the format while your creating the report.

- 1-click file
- 2-New Report
- 3-choose the type of report
- 4-add the source (data file or query)
- 5-hit next till Paper size windows
- 6-You now can choose a format(in the list) from options area.
- Then click finish.

Comment: Yes I know it. I need to change it from A4 to letter each time I create a new Report.

I want to know is I can set WINDEV to always propose letter. So I will no longer have to change it.